# Cannot message users who are not admins, developers or testers of the app until pages_messaging permission is reviewed and the app is live

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'am building bot with microsoft bot framework. 
Successfully published on azure and connected with [microsoft bot framework](https://dev.botframework.com).
For skype bot is working properly, but for facebook it shows an error :

> {"error":{"message":"(#10) Cannot message users who are not admins,
>   developers or testers of the app until pages_messaging permission is
>   reviewed and the app is
>   live.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"error_subcode":2018028,"fbtrace_id":"AXwQF7NQvLs"}}

I followed instructions from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110201/Creating-A-Facebook-Bot-Using-Microsoft-Bot-Framew) for my bot to facebook connection.

how long it takes to approve my application ?
and 
is approving my app is my only problem in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like if you haven't available your app to Public.

You can do that inside this URL:

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOURAPPID/review-status/

Inside this, you need to set the app available for the public.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly fine behaviour. All bots must be submited for a review before going public. If your bot is not public - only testers/devs/admins can communicate with bot.